# Strange cookie bug, javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I cannot figure out why this is happening at all. I have a form, and a button that calls a method that uses jQuery to serializes the form and sticks it into a cookie, here:

```
function serializeFormToCookie(){
var str = $("form").serialize();
alert(str);

document.cookie = str + "&expires=" + expires.toUTCString()

alert("You have successfully stored your reservation, please click show if you would like to review it.")
}
```

(When I do a quick check and just alert(str) the string is exactly as I expect it.

There is a second button that calls a show method here is the show method:

```
function showData(){
var savedCookie = document.cookie
var dataArray = savedCookie.split("&")
alert(dataArray[0]) //this is blank! it should be the first key value pair from str!
alert(dataArray[1]) //this is "; key=value" I have NO idea where the ";" is coming from!
alert(datArray[2....etc]) //this is perfect, comes up as key=value.  
}
```

Can anyone figure out what is going on here?

Comment: here is the form for completion sake: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7575853

Comment: The data you are serializing into might include an ampersand

Comment: Put what you are getting in **dataArray**

Comment: A simple alert(dataArray); yields:
,; fName=just,lName=,address1=,address2=,city=,state=,zip=,phone=,fax=,carType=,expires=Sat, 21 Dec 2013 03:39:07 GMT

Answer (score 0):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/c2znX/

**HTML:-**

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" />
    <input type="text" name="lastname"/>
    <input type="text" name="email" />
</form>

<input type="button" onclick="serializeFormToCookie()"  value="Store" />
<input type="button" onclick="showData()"  value="Show" />
```

**JS:-**

```
function serializeFormToCookie() {
    var str = $("form").serialize();
    alert(str);

    var expires = new Date("October 13, 2015 11:13:00");

    document.cookie = str + "&expires=" + expires.toUTCString();

    alert("You have successfully stored your reservation, please click show if you would like to review it.");
}

function showData() {
    var savedCookie = document.cookie;
    var dataArray = savedCookie.split("&");
    console.log(document.cookie);
    console.log(dataArray);
}
```

**Console.log**

```
Array[5]
0: "firstname=john"
1: "lastname=phillips"
2: "email=john%40philips.com"
3: "expires=Tue, 13 Oct 2015 05:43:00 GMT; csrftoken=4mJGsAuQ3DtgZ5HNLZJNBPkOwAqCH5zo; __utma=45159731.617712919.1381735611.1383277585.1384938305.3; __utmc=45159731; __utmz=45159731.1381735611.1.1.utmcsr=jsfiddle.net|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/S9Hgg/5/; PRUM_EPISODES=s=1384938369829"
4: "r=http%3A//fiddle.jshell.net/_display/test1.html; BCSI-CS-560d5cf3f6036b02=2"
length: 5
__proto__: Array[0]
```

Comment: @justinhenricks - Does this answer your question?

Comment: I can see that it is working in the jsfiddle version. My code still maintains this bug somewhere and I still cannot figure out what is causing it in my code. Thank you for the response